# Twilio only runs from my Python 3.7 directory on OS X

Tags: python, twilio

I installed Twilio:

```
pip3 install twilio
```

But it will run only from the Python 3 Applications folder.

```
// ♥ python3
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> import twilio
>>> print(twilio.__version__)
6.21.0
```

Here is what I get from any other folder:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import twilio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/davidtannenbaum/Dropbox (Personal)/pythonpractice/twilio.py", line 2, in <module>
print(twilio.__version__)
AttributeError: module 'twilio' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Anyone know why it works in the Python 3.7 directory and gives an error anywhere else? How do I fix this?

Comment: You have a name clash between the twillio library and a local file named `twillio.py`. Rename it.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!